# Where can I find information to declare constants for the multiboot header

Tags: assembly, operating-system, bootstrapping, osdev, multiboot

I am trying to develop my own OS, and following these tutorials.

https://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones

I understand i will be using GRUB/existing boot loader to load "kernel.c". Before the control is handed over to "kernel.c" i understand that the hardware isn't initialized, henceforth i will be setting up things such as memory map, stack etc.

I see that specific variables/hardware is set in the multi boot header

```
/* Declare constants for the multiboot header. */
.set ALIGN,    1<<0             /* align loaded modules on page boundaries */
.set MEMINFO,  1<<1             /* provide memory map */
.set FLAGS,    ALIGN | MEMINFO  /* this is the Multi boot 'flag' field */
.set MAGIC,    0x1BADB002       /* 'magic number' lets boot loader find the header */
.set CHECKSUM, -(MAGIC + FLAGS) /* checksum of above, to prove we are multi boot */
 
/*
```

Why specifically those mentioned in above code? Where can i find these multi boot headers?
Am i supposed to use specific ones related to my architecture specified by GRUB in following link?

https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot/multiboot.html#multiboot_002eh

Where can I learn more about bootstrap assembly for my further OS projects?

Comment: [Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot/multiboot.html#Top) is where this comes from.

Answer (score 1):

> Why specifically those mentioned in above code? Where can i find these multi
> boot headers? Am i supposed to use specific ones related to my architecture
> specified by GRUB in following link?

The multiboot documentation (which you linked) describes the meaning of those
flags (`ALIGN` = `MULTIBOOT_PAGE_ALIGN`, `MEMINFO` = `MULTIBOOT_MEMORY_INFO`).

As for why to use these flags specifically:

The `ALIGN` flag should not matter for you unless you use multiboot modules
(which the bare bones guide doesn't). It should be safe to remove.

The `MEMINFO` flag you very likely need in order to know which memory regions
are safe to use and which are reserved by hardware. The reason you let GRUB (or
any multiboot loader) do this for you is (1) that once you are in protected
mode, this information becomes more difficult to obtain - and protected mode is
how your kernel is entered and (2) it is beneficial to have this information
early on to guide memory management, if your OS uses dynamic memory.

Aside from those two flags, there is `MULTIBOOT_VIDEO_MODE` (which I haven't
found a use for) and `MULTIBOOT_AOUT_KLUDGE`, which is only interesting if you
use that executable format (the barebones guide doesn't).

> Where can I learn more about bootstrap assembly for my further OS projects?

When using a pre-existing bootloader, the amount of assembler bootstrap you
need is limited. I personally think the osdev wiki Bare Bones page does a
decent job to guide the reader through the steps, with all the inline
documentation. Though perhaps someone else can add additional links here.